# Derivative of formula for battery's output power is not right

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power, batteries

There is something about output power of battery in circuits that bothering me.
I hope you help me.
So we know the formula for power in electrical circuits is (current x voltage) or:
$$
P=IV
$$
and the voltage of a battery while there is a current running through it is:
$$
V = \varepsilon - Ir
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the electromotive force, and $r$ is the internal resistance of the battery.
Now if we replace $V$ in the power equation with the voltage of battery, we have:
$$
P = I(\varepsilon - Ir) = I\varepsilon-rI^2
$$
if we make a function out of it like this:
$$
P(I) = I\varepsilon - rI^2
$$
and graph it, we get something like this for example:
[image: graph]

My problem is the derivative of this function:
$$
\frac{dP}{dI} = \varepsilon - 2rI
$$
which is clearly not equal to the output voltage of the battery, but as far as I know, it should be. If there is something I'm mistaking about, please correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the equaiton for power:
$$P=IV.$$
It may seem at first that one can take the derivative of this expression with respect to the current and obtain:
$${dP(I)\over dI}=V,$$
however, this overlooks the fact that $V$ is a function $V=V(I)$, e.g. as you not in your own post:
$$V=\epsilon-Ir.$$
So that in reality you have no reason to expect that the derivative of power with respect to current is $V$, rather:
$${dP(I)\over dI}={dI\over dI}V+I{dV\over dI}=(\epsilon-Ir)+I(-r)=\epsilon-2Ir.$$ Where I have used the "product rule",
$${dfg\over dx}={df\over dx}g+f{dg\over dx},$$
for taking the derivative of a product of functions. You don't have to use the product rule, you can indeed take the derivative by writing out the function for $P$ explicitly then differentiating, like you did in your example; however, the product rule can be handy for more complicated examples. Thus, your work was correct except for your expectation that the derivative of $P$ should be $V$.